# How to convert linux/mac source code into windows vs2010 source code?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6 with VS2010 in Windows 7. I could not include #include"X11/Xlib.h" and #include "X11/Xutil.h" header file in windows program. I think #include"X11/Xlib.h" and #include "X11/Xutil.h" are linux or Mac header files. Which header file I can use in windows instead of #include"X11/Xlib.h" and #include "X11/Xutil.h".  Can anyone help me about it?

The source code link:
https://github.com/jujojujo2003/OpenCVHandGuesture/blob/master/main.cpp

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//This function returns the square of the euclidean distance between 2 points.
double dist(Point x,Point y)
{
return (x.x-y.x)*(x.x-y.x)+(x.y-y.y)*(x.y-y.y);
}


//This function returns the radius and the center of the circle given 3 points
//If a circle cannot be formed , it returns a zero radius circle centered at (0,0)
pair<Point,double> circleFromPoints(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
{
double offset = pow(p2.x,2) +pow(p2.y,2);
double bc = ( pow(p1.x,2) + pow(p1.y,2) - offset )/2.0;
double cd = (offset - pow(p3.x, 2) - pow(p3.y, 2))/2.0;
double det = (p1.x - p2.x) * (p2.y - p3.y) - (p2.x - p3.x)* (p1.y - p2.y);
double TOL = 0.0000001;
if (abs(det) < TOL) { cout<<"POINTS TOO CLOSE"<<endl;return make_pair(Point(0,0),0); }

double idet = 1/det;
double centerx = (bc * (p2.y - p3.y) - cd * (p1.y - p2.y)) * idet;
double centery = (cd * (p1.x - p2.x) - bc * (p2.x - p3.x)) * idet;
double radius = sqrt( pow(p2.x - centerx,2) + pow(p2.y-centery,2));

return make_pair(Point(centerx,centery),radius);
}

//When called , it simulates a click at the curent mouse cursor location
void mouseClick()
{
int button=Button1;
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

XEvent event;

if(display == NULL)
{
cout<<"Error connecting to display"<<endl;
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
memset(&event, 0x00, sizeof(event));

event.type = ButtonPress;
event.xbutton.button = button;
event.xbutton.same_screen = True;
XQueryPointer(display, RootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display)), &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.window, &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root, &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y, &event.xbutton.state);
event.xbutton.subwindow = event.xbutton.window;
while(event.xbutton.subwindow)
{
event.xbutton.window = event.xbutton.subwindow;
XQueryPointer(display, event.xbutton.window, &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.subwindow, &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root, &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y, &event.xbutton.state);
}

if(XSendEvent(display, PointerWindow, True, 0xfff, &event) == 0) cout<<"ERROR SENDING CLICK"<<endl;

XFlush(display);

XCloseDisplay(display);
}

//When called, it simulates a mouse release event at the current cursor location
void mouseRelease()
{
int button=Button1;
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

XEvent event;

if(display == NULL)
{
cout<<"Error connecting to display"<<endl;
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
memset(&event, 0x00, sizeof(event));

event.xbutton.button = button;
event.xbutton.same_screen = True;
XQueryPointer(display, RootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display)), &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.window, &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root, &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y, &event.xbutton.state);
event.xbutton.subwindow = event.xbutton.window;
while(event.xbutton.subwindow)
{
event.xbutton.window = event.xbutton.subwindow;
XQueryPointer(display, event.xbutton.window, &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.subwindow, &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root, &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y, &event.xbutton.state);
}


event.type = ButtonRelease;
event.xbutton.state = 0x100;

if(XSendEvent(display, PointerWindow, True, 0xfff, &event) == 0) cout<<"ERROR RELEASING"<<endl;

XFlush(display);

XCloseDisplay(display);
}


//This function moves the mouse cursor to (x,y)
void mouseTo(int x,int y)
{
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
XWarpPointer(display, None, root, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, y);
XFlush(display);
XCloseDisplay(display);
}


//The main function :D
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Mat frame;
Mat back;
Mat fore;
vector<pair<Point,double> > palm_centers;
VideoCapture cap(0);
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;
bg.set("nmixtures",3);
bg.set("detectShadows",false);


namedWindow("Frame");
namedWindow("Background");
int backgroundFrame=500;


for(;;)
{
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
//Get the frame
cap >> frame;

//Update the current background model and get the foreground
if(backgroundFrame>0)
{bg.operator ()(frame,fore);backgroundFrame--;}
else
{bg.operator()(frame,fore,0);}

//Get background image to display it
bg.getBackgroundImage(back);


//Enhance edges in the foreground by applying erosion and dilation
erode(fore,fore,Mat());
dilate(fore,fore,Mat());


//Find the contours in the foreground
findContours(fore,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
//Ignore all small insignificant areas
if(contourArea(contours[i])>=5000)  
{
//Draw contour
vector<vector<Point> > tcontours;
tcontours.push_back(contours[i]);
drawContours(frame,tcontours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);

//Detect Hull in current contour
vector<vector<Point> > hulls(1);
vector<vector<int> > hullsI(1);
convexHull(Mat(tcontours[0]),hulls[0],false);
convexHull(Mat(tcontours[0]),hullsI[0],false);
drawContours(frame,hulls,-1,cv::Scalar(0,255,0),2);

//Find minimum area rectangle to enclose hand
RotatedRect rect=minAreaRect(Mat(tcontours[0]));

//Find Convex Defects
vector<Vec4i> defects;
if(hullsI[0].size()>0)
{
Point2f rect_points[4]; rect.points( rect_points );
for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
line( frame, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j+1)%4], Scalar(255,0,0), 1, 8 );
Point rough_palm_center;
convexityDefects(tcontours[0], hullsI[0], defects);
if(defects.size()>=3)
{
vector<Point> palm_points;
for(int j=0;j<defects.size();j++)
{
int startidx=defects[j][0]; Point ptStart( tcontours[0][startidx] );
int endidx=defects[j][1]; Point ptEnd( tcontours[0][endidx] );
int faridx=defects[j][2]; Point ptFar( tcontours[0][faridx] );
//Sum up all the hull and defect points to compute average
rough_palm_center+=ptFar+ptStart+ptEnd;
palm_points.push_back(ptFar);
palm_points.push_back(ptStart);
palm_points.push_back(ptEnd);
}

//Get palm center by 1st getting the average of all defect points, this is the rough palm center,
//Then U chose the closest 3 points ang get the circle radius and center formed from them which is the palm center.
rough_palm_center.x/=defects.size()*3;
rough_palm_center.y/=defects.size()*3;
Point closest_pt=palm_points[0];
vector<pair<double,int> > distvec;
for(int i=0;i<palm_points.size();i++)
distvec.push_back(make_pair(dist(rough_palm_center,palm_points[i]),i));
sort(distvec.begin(),distvec.end());

//Keep choosing 3 points till you find a circle with a valid radius
//As there is a high chance that the closes points might be in a linear line or too close that it forms a very large circle
pair<Point,double> soln_circle;
for(int i=0;i+2<distvec.size();i++)
{
Point p1=palm_points[distvec[i+0].second];
Point p2=palm_points[distvec[i+1].second];
Point p3=palm_points[distvec[i+2].second];
soln_circle=circleFromPoints(p1,p2,p3);//Final palm center,radius
if(soln_circle.second!=0)
break;
}

//Find avg palm centers for the last few frames to stabilize its centers, also find the avg radius
palm_centers.push_back(soln_circle);
if(palm_centers.size()>10)
palm_centers.erase(palm_centers.begin());

Point palm_center;
double radius=0;
for(int i=0;i<palm_centers.size();i++)
{
palm_center+=palm_centers[i].first;
radius+=palm_centers[i].second;
}
palm_center.x/=palm_centers.size();
palm_center.y/=palm_centers.size();
radius/=palm_centers.size();

//Draw the palm center and the palm circle
//The size of the palm gives the depth of the hand
circle(frame,palm_center,5,Scalar(144,144,255),3);
circle(frame,palm_center,radius,Scalar(144,144,255),2);

//Detect fingers by finding points that form an almost isosceles triangle with certain thesholds
int no_of_fingers=0;
for(int j=0;j<defects.size();j++)
{
int startidx=defects[j][0]; Point ptStart( tcontours[0][startidx] );
int endidx=defects[j][1]; Point ptEnd( tcontours[0][endidx] );
int faridx=defects[j][2]; Point ptFar( tcontours[0][faridx] );
//X o--------------------------o Y
double Xdist=sqrt(dist(palm_center,ptFar));
double Ydist=sqrt(dist(palm_center,ptStart));
double length=sqrt(dist(ptFar,ptStart));

double retLength=sqrt(dist(ptEnd,ptFar));
//Play with these thresholds to improve performance
if(length<=3*radius&&Ydist>=0.4*radius&&length>=10&&retLength>=10&&max(length,retLength)/min(length,retLength)>=0.8)
if(min(Xdist,Ydist)/max(Xdist,Ydist)<=0.8)
{
if((Xdist>=0.1*radius&&Xdist<=1.3*radius&&Xdist<Ydist)||(Ydist>=0.1*radius&&Ydist<=1.3*radius&&Xdist>Ydist))
line( frame, ptEnd, ptFar, Scalar(0,255,0), 1 ),no_of_fingers++;
}


}

no_of_fingers=min(5,no_of_fingers);
cout<<"NO OF FINGERS: "<<no_of_fingers<<endl;
mouseTo(palm_center.x,palm_center.y);//Move the cursor corresponding to the palm
if(no_of_fingers<4)//If no of fingers is <4 , click , else release
mouseClick();
else
mouseRelease();

}
}

}
if(backgroundFrame>0)
putText(frame, "Recording Background", cvPoint(30,30), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(200,200,250), 1, CV_AA);
imshow("Frame",frame);
imshow("Background",back);
if(waitKey(10) >= 0) break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uhhh.... You can't convert the code, you have to completely rewrite it. You have there an X11 application, and Windows doesn't have X11, it uses a completely different model for GUIs.

Alternatively, if you're not fixated on Visual Studio (why would you be?) it would be much less work to compile against cygwin's X. You'd have to bundle it though when distributing your application, and it wouldn't look "native".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this resource may help you (I used it once):
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

Porting code is often a hard task that one has to face on some day :D